# Can partitions in one Kafka topic have different replication factors?

Tags: apache-kafka, replication

When defininig a kafka topic, I can set the replication factor, and usually Kafka will distribute the partitions across the available brokers.

Say I have 3 brokers and have a topic with several partitions and a replication-factor=2, then 
some partitions will be set to be on brokers [0,1], some one [0,2] and some on [1,2] (ignoring the leader selection/preference for now)

Can I later eg set only one partition to have a replication factor of 3 (and thus add this partition to the remaining node) without having to also do this for the other partitions?
Is there any drawback to having a number !=all of the partitions replicated to more/less nodes than the others?

All documentation etc I saw only ever speaks of the replication factor in terms of whole topics

I know I use kafka-reassign-partitions on a per-partition basis, but I found no discussion or recommendations on whether it is good/bad to only reassign a few partitions or what the dangers (if any) might be

Answer (score 0):

Only topics have replication factors, not partitions.

Partitions can become *out-of-sync*, and lose leadership in the case of errors, in which case, one or more partitions becomes unavailable, but the topic is still the source of how many replicas there ought to be

> I found no discussion or recommendations on whether it is good/bad to only reassign a few partitions

You'd usually only do this for maintenance or cluster expansion to remove large partitions from occupying too much disk space on certain brokers.

The main "bad" thing would be how fast your network is to transfer the partition while still handling traffic to the other replicas of the topic.

Comment: "Only topics have replication factors, not partitions", yes, but in a kafka-reassign-partitions, input file I could list only a few partitions of one topic and then give those partitions more nodes to be assigned to than the remaining ones.. Will that hurt (and yes, this is mostly for maintenance (shuffling things around, trying to clean up a problem with log file name increases that cause the log-cleaner to die (this is an old version of Kafka that I cannot upgrade at this time)

Comment: The input file defines the partitions and all its replicas. There's no way to move an topic in one action. If your cluster is already broken with corrupt logs, then I'm not sure moving them to a new host would do any good. Typically, we just delete the corrupt broker partitions, then let it re-replicate from healthy nodes

Comment: Correct. Theoretically on a topic with 12 partitions I could list only 1 or 2 partitions with now 3 (instead of the prior 2) nodes for replication, and when that is run have only those 1 or 2 partitions replicated to 3 nodes. and the other stay on 2 nodes. I want to know if that is possible or bad.

Comment: my problem is that after I did what you said (remove the bad partition data on the bad replica, restart and let it replicate again), I get files with too large jump in the  filenames (indicating more than 88m messages [ a compacting topic] so the logCleaner claims it cannot handle that. However on the leader the partitions has more files with less jumps in the filenames... I know about the 'change the filename to indicate lesser number of messages' trick (from Kafka-3894 but that sounds dangerous, specifically as I don't know how many messages really are in that logfile...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're worried about. If you need to move partitions, then it's not bad. If the cluster is healthy, you're just needlessly moving things around

Comment: You can use the log dump utility to get the message count per file

Comment: so my hope is to just have this one partition replicate to the 3rd node, and see if that replicates properly (with not that one large message jump in the filename). If so, I can remove the replication to the bad node 1, and then re-do that replication from scratch.. Else I'd have to find a way to delete the topic completely and stream all data to a replacement topic (and then back...) to get it all refreshed. That will likely cause downtime